# How can overlapping nodefaces be generated in ETE3?

Tags: python-3.x, ete3

I want to generate overlapping node faces. Currently, vertical distance (y-coordinate) of nodes changes with the size of node face.

If you know how to achieve overlapping node face, please share the code.

Thanks